# Error: 13 INTERNAL: Serialization failure (Usign Google Cloud Vision Api)

Tags: node.js, grpc, google-cloud-vision, grpc-node

I am having this error after sending a Base64 of a photo taken in a react-native to vision api, I read in some places that the error must be in the grpc however, I am not using any of it directly, I am just using the structure vision api text detection basics

```
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");

async function sendImage(base64) {
  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({
    keyFilename: "**************",
  });

  const [result] = await client.textDetection({
    image: {
      content: base64,
    },
  });

  const detections = result.textAnnotations;
  return detections;
}

module.exports = sendImage;
```

Comment: "this error" What error?

Comment: the error on the title: "Error: 13 INTERNAL: Serialization failure"